# How to display date as text in Access report

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to get Access to create a certificate for me. I've got almost everything worked out except for the date. I want the date to display as text.

I'm able to accomplish this with a module in Excel, but when I input it into Access as a function, it gives me a #Name? error. Here's what I have in the function (again, this works in Excel):

```
Function DateToWords(ByVal xRgVal As Date) As String
   Dim xYear As String
   Dim Hundreds As String
   Dim Decades As String
   Dim xTensArr As Variant
   Dim xOrdArr As Variant
   Dim xCardArr As Variant
   xOrdArr = Array("1st", "2nd", "3rd", "4th", "5th", "6th", _
               "7th", "8th", "9th", "10th", "11th", "12th", _
               "13th", "14th", "15th", "16th", "17th", "18th", _
               "19th", "20th", "21st", "22nd", _
               "23rd", "24th", "25th", "26th", _
               "27th", "28th", "29th", "30th", "31st")
   xCardArr = Array("", "one", "two", "three", "tour", _
               "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", _
               "ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", _
               "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", _
               "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen")
   xTensArr = Array("twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", _
           "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety")
   xYear = CStr(Year(xRgVal))
   Decades = Mid$(xYear, 3)
   If CInt(Decades) < 20 Then
    Decades = xCardArr(CInt(Decades))
   ElseIf CInt(Decades) Like "*0" Then
    Decades = xTensArr(CInt(Left$(Decades, 1)) - 2)
   Else
    Decades = xTensArr(CInt(Left$(Decades, 1)) - 2) & "-" & _
            xCardArr(CInt(Right$(Decades, 1)))
   End If
    Hundreds = Mid$(xYear, 2, 1)
   If CInt(Hundreds) Then
    Hundreds = xCardArr(CInt(Hundreds)) & " hundred "
   Else
    Hundreds = ""
   End If
   DateToWords = "This " & xOrdArr(Day(xRgVal) - 1) & " day of" & _
              Format$(xRgVal, " mmmm, ") & _
              xCardArr(CInt(Left$(xYear, 1))) & _
              " thousand " & Hundreds & Decades
End Function
```

Code in Access that calls the function. This is in the text box on the report:

```
=DateToWords([Forms]![FrmMakeCert]![Date])
```

n Excel, this takes the date that I specify in a cell (e.g. 12/27/18) and turns it into:

"This 27th day of December, two-thousand eighteen"

That's what I'd like to accomplish in the Access report, pulling the date from a form.

Comment: The function works perfect for me. The function is in a general module? Edit question to show the code that calls the function.

Comment: Are you asking how to call this function in an Access report, or are you having a problem with the function itself?

Comment: Edited to add call to function

Comment: Scrubbed down version in Google Drive:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oXEiECM5Go6KbungPIVHD60xu3ouc0qt/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You used the same name for both function and module. Names should be different. Rename your module to mdlDateToWords.

Comment: That was it! You sir or maam. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was caused by using the same name for both user-defined function and module namely DateToWords.
You should use different names.
Rename the module to, for instance, mdlDateToWords.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to use.

- First create a module in access and paste your codes.
- Suppose in report you are displaying date to text in a textbox name `txtDateText`
- In `txtDateText` data source enter following

  `=DateToWords([Forms]![Form1]![txtDate])`

***Remember:*** Form1 must be open and contain valid date otherwise it will show error. Form1 is form name, so it will be different in your case. Also text box name.

[***File download link***](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DGfEM6B2JPzzrmHckb6bVDQxEju5EXqC/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

Comment: That's what I did. But I'm still getting a #name error. Could it be because I'm using a date picker in the form to pick the date?

Comment: Date picker is not issue. You are refereeing wrong text box, may textbox name is not correct. Can you share a sample file via dropbox or google drive, so that we can have a look. I have tested in my side and found everything is okay.

Comment: Another thing, your form is open or not?

Comment: Also, the little box in the upper left of my cert above is pulling the date from the same form. I stuck it there to make sure it was pulling correctly.

Comment: OK, I scrubbed it down real quick and stuck it in Google Drive:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oXEiECM5Go6KbungPIVHD60xu3ouc0qt/view?usp=sharing

Comment: As stated in comments above. It was sue to my naming conventions in the module.

Comment: Download the file. Problem was in your date textbox in makecert form. It was not properly date formatted. Also `Date` is a reserve word as well as builtin function. So, it is recommended not to use `Date` as any control name. [Download Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DGfEM6B2JPzzrmHckb6bVDQxEju5EXqC/view?usp=sharing)